# AndroidAnnotations bean initialize when OnActivityResult called

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult, android-annotations

**EDIT**

This problem is due to ViewPager+TabInfo UI structure, which child fragments are re-instanciated when `AddTab` performed. I post a reply accordingly.

**ORIGINAL POST BELOW**

In below code, the bean `injectedListAdapter` is not initialized(null) but also `@AfterInject` and `@AfterView` are not executed when `@OnActivityResult` is invoked.

For that,
1. How can I make `OnActivityResult` called after `@Bean` injected?
2. And, can I make to execute `OnActivityResult` after `@AfterViews`?

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_list_main)
public class MainListFragment extends Fragment {
    @Bean
    InjectedListAdapter injectedListAdapter;

    @AfterInject
    void initValues() {
        // ...
    }

    @AfterViews
    void initViews() {
        // ...
    }

    @OnActivityResult(CommonValue.REQUEST_CODE_A)
    void onResult(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        injectedListAdapter.doSomething(); // <- injectedListAdapter is null.
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not really understand the problem. The `onResult` method is called, when an Activity started from `MainListFragment` returns. Those injections happen at initialization. These are independent events, but generally the initialization should be first, since you should start the `Activity` after init in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry @WonderCsabo

My problem is related to **TabInfo+ViewPager** UI structure and its children fragments.

below code is darn dirty but works.

In adapter,

```
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    public void addTab(ImageButton btn, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
    TabInfo info = null;
    if (mContext.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() != null && mContext.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() > 0) {
        for (Fragment fragment : mContext.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            if((int)btn.getTag() == 0 && fragment instanceof Fragment1_){
                info = new TabInfo(fragment.getClass(), fragment, btn, args);
                continue;
            }
            if((int)btn.getTag() == 1 && fragment instanceof Fragment2_){
                info = new TabInfo(fragment.getClass(), fragment, btn, args);
                continue;
            }
            if((int)btn.getTag() == 2 && fragment instanceof Fragment3_)
            {
                info = new TabInfo(fragment.getClass(), fragment, btn, args);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    if(info == null) {
        info = new TabInfo(clss, null, btn, args);
    }

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    mTabs.add(info);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And Activity which contains ViewPager, each tab button has index value of `Tag`. As my app only has static tab pages, it is enough to do hard-coded work.

```
@AfterViews
void initViews() { // you can put it in OnCreate()
        imageButtonList.setTag(0);
    imageButtonGroup.setTag(1);
    imageButtonProfile.setTag(2);
    mMainPagerAdapter.addTab(imageButton1, Fragment1_.class, null);
    mMainPagerAdapter.addTab(imageButton2, Fragment2_.class, null);
    mMainPagerAdapter.addTab(imageButton3, Fragment3_.class, null);
}
```